# How to remove the ROW_NUMBER function?

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2014

Does anyone know how to remove the ROW_NUMBER function of this query, how query should look like in the end? 
Query shows how long is the execution of the package. Thank you.

```
WITH PkgStart AS (
    SELECT p.executionid,
           p.source,
           p.starttime,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.executionid
                                 ORDER BY p.id ASC) AS rk
      FROM sysssislog p where event='OnPreExecute')
      ,PkgEnd AS (
    SELECT p.executionid,
           p.source,
           p.endtime,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.executionid
                                 ORDER BY p.id DESC) AS rk
      FROM sysssislog p where event='OnPostExecute')

SELECT A.source
, RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,A.StartTime, B.EndTime)/60
AS VARCHAR(20)),3) + ' min.' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,A.StartTime, B.EndTime)%60
AS VARCHAR(20)),2) + ' sec.' AS Duration
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),A.starttime,108) 'Start Time'
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),B.endtime,108) 'End Time'
FROM
(
SELECT s.*
FROM PkgStart s
WHERE s.rk = 1
) A INNER JOIN
(
SELECT e.*
FROM PkgEnd e
WHERE e.rk = 1
)  B ON A.executionid=B.executionid
```

Comment: What's the problem with this query? Windowing functions are usually there for a reason.

Comment: The query is all fine, but it is currently not required ROW_NUMBER function, and i don't know how to remove.

Comment: Delete the row? Also, it is used in your where clauses so you would have to remove these too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I did so.